# extending IP range for postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, containers

Docker container, ubuntu20 it is. 
I have manually installed postgres 12.9  in it.

when I do `PGPASSWORD='mysecretpassword' psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost` (or 127.0.0.1) from inside a docker it works 100% OK - psql console appears

The problem appears when I try to replace `localhost` with non-loopback IP number. It either hangs or prints:

```
PGPASSWORD='mysecretpassword' psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h  172.17.0.5 
psql: error: connection to server at "172.17.0.5", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Also, what somehow is understandable, it prints same error when trying to access it from external machine (docker-host).
My /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf is:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all            127.0.0.1/32              md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all            127.0.0.1/32              md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5


host    all             all            172.17.0.0/24              md5
host    replication     all            172.17.0.0/24              md5
```

with 2 lines at the end are added by me... unfortunately still it doesn't work.
Tried various other options 0.0.0.0/32 etc... can any1 explain me how to open my psql to all IPs ?

Comment: You probably forgot to set `listen_addresses = '*'` and restart.

Comment: yep !  that's listen_addresses